# How to apply a shap explainer on a linear regression model from pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, linear-regression, shap

I am trying to apply one of the shap explainer functions on my linear regression model generated with pyspark in order to find feature importance for every single prediction.
It apparently works fine only for linear regression models generated with sklearn when applying the LinearExplainer() function from shap. When I apply the same function on an equivalent model generated with pyspark, there comes always the same error *"InvalidModelError: An unknown model type was passed: <class 'pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression'>"*. But in the documentation it is stated that shap also works for pyspark, but there is no concrete code example.

Here is my code:

```
training_length = int(df.count()*0.80)
train_df = df.limit(training_length)
test_df = df.exceptAll(train_df)

from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='SALES_VOLUME', maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
lr_model = lr.fit(train_df)

import shap
shap.initjs()
explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(lr, train_df)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(train_df)
```